# Processing - Backwards car somersault

Tags: processing

I have to write a program showing a car somersaulting backwards while flying through the air in correct projectile motion, landing on its wheels.

The code I have so far allows me to have the car fly through the air. All I need is to rotate the car backwards and properly land on its wheels.

Code I currently have:

```
float x,y;
float s = 20;
float theta = 0.64;
float g = 9.8;
float t =0.0;
PImage img;
void setup(){
  size(750,600);
  img = loadImage("myimage.gif");

  noStroke();
  smooth();
}

void draw(){
   fill(0, 22);
   rect(0, 0, width, height);
   t = t+0.01;
   x = s*cos(theta)*t;
   y = (s*t*sin(theta))-(0.5*g*t*t);
   fill(255);
   image(img,x*15,550-y*5);
}
```

Image I'm using for the car:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`rotate()`](https://processing.org/reference/rotate_.html) to rotate the car around its relative position and [`translate()`](https://processing.org/reference/translate_.html) to move the car to its position.

```java
translate(x*15,550-y*5);
rotate(r);
image(img, 0, 0);
```

The rotation angle (`r`) has to increase by time (*r= f(t)*):

```java
float r = alpha * t;
```

See the example:

[image]

```java
float s = 20;
float theta = 0.64;
float g = 9.8;
float t = 0.0;
float alpha = -2.2;
PImage img;

void setup(){
    size(750,600);
    img = loadImage("car.gif");
    noStroke();
    smooth();
}

void draw(){
   float x = s*cos(theta)*t;
   float y = (s*t*sin(theta))-(0.5*g*t*t);
   float r = alpha * t;
   t += 0.01;

   background(0);

   translate(x*15,550-y*5);
   rotate(r);
   image(img, 0, 0);

   if (t > 3.141529) 
       t = 0.0;
}
```